# Configure dbms_metadata.get_ddl() to leave off schema?

Tags: oracle

Can I configure `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` to leave off the schema name of generated objects?

I set these transform parameters

```
begin
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'PRETTY',true);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SQLTERMINATOR',true);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
end;
```

and execute this query

```
select to_char(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','FOO')) from dual;
```

and receive this ddl for my table.  I would like to have just `"FOO"` rather than `"MH"."FOO"`.

```
CREATE TABLE "MH"."FOO"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
(   "X" NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find a way of doing this in an answer to [Generating DDL script for object without schema name baked in using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31725592/635608) on Stack Overflow: use the `EMIT_SCHEMA` transform:

```
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(
      dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', false);
```

This transform is, as far as I can tell, undocumented. (Probably exists at least down to 9.2.) You can find it mentioned in two support documents:

- [EXPORT SCHEMA OF 9203 FAILS WITH EXP-00056 and ORA-31600 (Doc ID 257986.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=257986.1)
- [Bug 17801303 - DBMS_METADATA returns two DDLs separated by semi-column for a User Defined Type (Doc ID 17801303.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=17801303.8)